# Matlab: How to generate 0x0 struct array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

I got an .mat file with a variable `X`:

```
>> open('3rdPartyInputfile.mat')
>> X

X = 

0x0 struct array with fields:
    a
    b
```

I tried to create a similar variable like:

```
>> X1(1).a = [];
>> X1(1).b = [];
>> X1(1)=[]

X1 = 

1x0 struct array with fields:
    a
    b


>> X2(1).a = [];
>> X2(1).b = [];
>> X2(:,:)=[]

X2 = 

0x1 struct array with fields:
    a
    b
```

Which is close but not identical. The size here are 1x0 or 0x1, instead of the desired 0x0.

How to get it to 0x0?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get a 0x0 struct you can use

```
X = struct('a',{},'b',{})
```

Comment: Definitely the way to go for initialization. It seems that if you want to adjust existing code, you just need to make the first element `{}`. For example  `X = struct('a',{},'b',[])`

Answer (score 4):

In case you have an existing struct `x` and want to scale it down to 0x0, you could do the following:

```
 y=repmat(x,0,0)
```

Comment: Also a good option. Anyhow, the scaling down in my first tries, was just a workaround which didn't work.

Comment: @BerndGit If you say the scaling down is a 'workaround' you may actually want the initialization? In that case I suppose Nemesis should keep the acceptance checkmark (Note that giving it to me took it away from him). -- Of course, if you were looking for a way to scale your struct down I wouldn't mind keeping it.

Comment: Yeah. Since I'm new in the community here, I didn't know, that you can only apply one acceptance checkmark. Issue was fixed immediately after finding out. Anyhow also Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: an example of how screwy matlab can be ... beautiful!

Comment: not worth a separate answer but similarly referencing `x` with an empty double array achieves the same... e.g. `y = x([])`, or for n-dimensional empty `y = x(double.empty(zeros(1,n)))`

Comment: @RTL included the basic solution in my answer, I guess the rest is a bit beyond the scope. Note that  `y = x(logical.empty(zeros(1,4)))` 'just' produces a 2 dimensional empty struct. A bit of a surprise to me.